# What is the best way seperate the routing of different modules in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, bloc

Right now Im using generated routing. I have a class that returns all my routes to the onGenerateRoute. I have several modules in my app, which i have seperated. Accessible modules depend on the type of user. Im trying to create a different routes file for each module and have access to them from the main routes file. I am using bloc state management. (my routes file is starting to get really cluttered.)

Answer (score 1):

One way I've done it is via nested navigation and using multiple Navigator widgets, each of which manages a group of routes (this is if you're using **Navigator 1.0**).

For example; in the main routes object, you can have the routes to each module widget: User and Admin:

```dart
routes: {
   '/user': (context) => UserWidget(),
   '/admin': (context) => AdminWidget()
}
```

Then inside each of these widgets (which define your separate modules) you can have a nested Navigator widget that lays out the routes for each module (some "pseudo" code to get the idea):

```
class AdminWidget 
- Navigator
   - onGenerateRoute
     - '/admin_page1'
     - '/admin_page2'
     - '/admin_page3'
```

```
class UserWidget 
- Navigator
  - onGenerateRoute
    - '/user_page1'
    - '/user_page2'
    - '/user_page3'
```

That way you can group your routes and direct users to the corresponding routes based on their type or role. This is one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is create a router for each module and register these routers in the main router.

In your main router, you register the module routers.

Here's how I did mine:

App Router:

```
class AppRouter {
  AppRouter._();
  static final _instance = AppRouter._();
  factory AppRouter() => _instance;

  final _moduleRouterRegistration = <SubRouter>[
    moduleARouter,
    moduleBRouter,
  ];

  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final routeComponents = settings.name!.split(' ');
    //Backward compatibility check
    if (routeComponents.length == 1) {
      return MainAppRouter.generateRoutes(settings);
    }

    final module = _moduleRouterRegistration.firstWhere(
      (subRouter) => subRouter.moduleName == routeComponents[0],
      orElse: () => throw Exception(
        'Module with name ${routeComponents[0]} not registered in Router',
      ),
    );
    final routeName = routeComponents[1];
    final splitRouteSettings = RouteSettings(
      name: routeName,
      arguments: settings.arguments,
    );
    return Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => module.router(splitRouteSettings),
            settings: splitRouteSettings,
          )
        : MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => module.router(splitRouteSettings),
            settings: splitRouteSettings,
          );
  }
}
```

Main/Existing Router:

```
abstract class MainAppRouter {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoutes(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case dashboardRoute:
        return getPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          view: const MyHomePage(),
        );
      case normalARoute:
        return getPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          view: const NormalA(),
        );
      case normalBRoute:
        return getPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          view: const NormalB(),
        );
      default:
        return getPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          view: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}'),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }

  static PageRoute<dynamic> getPageRoute({
    required RouteSettings settings,
    required Widget view,
  }) {
    return Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoPageRoute(settings: settings, builder: (_) => view)
        : MaterialPageRoute(settings: settings, builder: (_) => view);
  }
}
```

Sub router interface:

```
abstract class SubRouter {
  String get moduleName;
  Widget router(RouteSettings settings);
}
```

Sub router:

```
final moduleARouter = _ModuleARouter();

class _ModuleARouter implements SubRouter {
  @override
  String get moduleName => 'moduleA';

  @override
  Widget router(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case aOneRoute:
        return ViewAOne();
      case aTwoRoute:
        return const ViewATwo();
      case aThreeRoute:
        return ViewAThree();
      default:
        return const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Cannot find route',
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

AppRouter().onGenerateRoute is registered as the onGenerateRoute method of the material app.

You could check the github repo for a working sample
https://github.com/mastersam07/s-p-h-r-